# Does the Python Tweepy 'userstream' method still work?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have the following code:

```
import tweepy

ckey =''
csecret =''
atoken =''
asecret =''

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)
    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener , tweet_mode='extended')

myStream.userstream(async=True)
```

When it runs, it will print out a response code of '410', which is:

> "This resource is gone. Used to indicate that an API endpoint has been
>   turned off."

I used this method earlier this year, but coming back to it recently, I find it is not working.

Can anyone confirm if this method is still working?  I saw something about Twitter deprecating some functions, but was not sure if this was one of those functions.

As a work around, I am using:

```
mystream.filter(follow=['123123123'], async=True)
```

I am using Tweepy 3.6.0, Python 3.6.1 (Windows 7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all the web searching I did for this, I did not get back this link from github discussing this exact issue.

https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1092

Basically, tweepy.userstream is now broke, and you need to use the .filter to get users feeds streamed.